# Convert linked excel into embedded excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a ppt presentation with hundreds of charts that are all linked to the same .xls file. I want to send the presentation to the client and I want him to be able to access the data. However, I do not want him to open the entire xls file when he clicks on edit data.

So what I would like to do is to "convert" the linked charts to charts with an embedded excel that only contains the data concerning the specific chart. 
(I am not sure if that's the right way to put it. I feel like the distinction between embedded and linked is not as clear cut anymore as it used to be in previous office versions)

I have found a macro for ppt 2003 that simply copies the old chart and does

`Set oSh2 = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject)(1)`

but I think this does now longer work ( I am working with ppt 2013).

Any ideas on how to do this are highly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: What occurs when you try the example code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to give him access to the entire original workbook/worksheet, you'll need to create multiple worksheets, each with just the data you DO want him to be able to get at and then either link or embed those into your PPT file.

If you create the charts using the old MS Graph mini-app (still included, if optionally, with Office) you can link data from an external Excel file into the graph datasheet. I'm almost certain that doing it this way will give others access to the graph datasheet (ie JUST the data used for the graph) but not to the linked source XL file.

I don't see a way of doing this with the new chart engine.

Comment: Thanks! I guessed that it would be difficult. I am trying to find the MS Graph mini app but I can't manage to find it. Is that supposed to be an add-In? Could you maybe point me to how to find it?

Comment: It may not be installed by default; I don't recall.  But if it's there, you'd use Insert | Object | Create New | Microsoft Graph Chart.  Unless you also make changes to the registry, PPT will keep offering to "update" the graph to the new chart types.  You'll want to test to make sure that won't undo all of your work if the recipient accepts that offer.